# cant see edit mode in front viewport blender 2.8

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, edit-mode

i cant see any vertices or faces or any kind of grid in the front viewport. 
In 3D mode when i shift around they appear as you can see in picture 1.
however when i click '1' in the numpad to go to front view edit i cant see any geometry- no edit grids or lines. i can only see it if i click wireframe mode. 
have i clicked something? everything in my viewport overlays is clicked on.
[image: image 1 3D mode]

[image: image 2 frontview port mode]

Answer (score 1):

You are probably viewing the back of your model rather than the front. Press CTRL+1 to view opposite side or/and ALT+Z to toggle transparency.

Comment: Hi - I tried both your suggestions- still not seeing any grids in the front view unfortunately.